Give access AWS Amplify to S3
I am trying to sync file from AWS Amplify to S3.
I get an Access denied error.
Here is my S3 policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1546414473940",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AwsAmplifyAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:amplify:eu-west-3:0000000000:apps/0000000000"
            },
            "Action":  [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
                ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}

Any advice ?

If you're accessing an Amplify created and managed bucket, then you grant permissions to the lambda or front-end via the amplify CLI tool. It appears you may be trying to access an S3 bucket that you created outside Amplify.
If that's the case, the following may help:
My Bucket Policy looks like this:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:Referer": "013456012345"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

The AWS Amplify managed Lambda that needs to access the bucket has a custom-policies.json file that looks like this:
[
  {
    "Action": [
      "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*",
  }
]

If you need additional permissions, add them. Note, 'listBucket' resource is just the bucket (no /), but get/put are the contents of the bucket, so you can spell out the path details (or /).
